# Allow uploading only one format in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

How to block upload of all formats, allow only one format to upload?

With the following code, you can block the upload of the desired formats, But with this code I might forget to block a format, I want to make a condittion that if the file was in jpg format, it would upload and not allow uploading any format other than jpg. In this way, I no longer need to search for each format and block them.

```
function cc_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    unset( $mimes['png'] );
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

Comment: So don't return the $mimes input array that only got some specific elements removed then - but return an array that contains only one single entry for `jpg` to begin with.

Comment: CBroe, thank you very much for the reply, How do I do this?

Comment: If you really only need the value from `$mimes['jpg']` - then return a new array, that contains that exact element, under the same key: `return ['jpg' => $mimes['jpg']];`

Comment: (Check if you really only need `jpg` though - sometimes JPEGs are also considered to be `jpeg`, so an additional second entry under that key might also exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of my good friend **CBroe**, my problem was solved with the following code :

```
function cc_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    $mimes = array(
        'jpg|jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
    );
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

**CBroe**, Thank you very much.